# How to stop storyboard animation delay?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have toolbars (wrapped by borders) that are created at runtime whenever needed.  I've added an animation method to grow or shrink the toolbar height when created or hidden respectively.

The problem is that even though the grow animation works fine, when I reverse the values and cause a shrink animation there is always a noticeable delay before the animation starts.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this and how to get around it?

Here is the code for my animation function:

```
        public static void AnimateBorder(Border border, int startHeight, int endHeight, int time)
    {
        DoubleAnimation stretch = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = startHeight,
            To = endHeight,
            Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, time),
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(stretch, border);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(stretch, new PropertyPath(Border.MaxHeightProperty));
        var sb = new Storyboard();

        // Add event handler to remove shrunk border.
        if (startHeight > endHeight)
        {
            sb.Completed += (sender, e) => Border_Collapsed(sender, e, border);
        }

        // Start animation.
        sb.Children.Add(stretch);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: As a note, you don't need a Storyboard. Call `border.BeginAnimation(Border.MaxHeightProperty, stretch)` instead. And is it really MaxHeight that you are animating? Why not Height?

Comment: And it isn't clear if you really start the shrink animation in the Completed handler of the grow animation. If the duration is fixed, why not just set the shrink animation's StartTime, or have a single auto-reverse animation?

Comment: I changed to Height and it seems to fix the delay I mentioned, but strangely the overall animation seems a lot slower.  How can I speed up the animation if I'm already using 1 second as the time duration?  The completed handler is only to dispose of the object once the shrink animation is complete (it doesn't handle start the animation).  I wanted a variable duration in case I end up with larger toolbars that will need longer to shrink.

Comment: You're using the wrong method to create a TimeSpan. Obviously a TimeSpan isn't limited to integer seconds. Use TimeSpan.FromSeconds instead.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thank you kindly.